# array to string conversion laravel databse seeds

Tags: php, laravel

**my seeds**

```
     [
                'id'             => 1,
                'album_title'           => '2022',
                'featured_image'             => 'index_1656159760.jpg',
                'featured_image_url'             => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/artists/albums/featured_image/index_1656159760.jpg',
                'genre_id'           => 4,
                'track_id'             => ["1","2"],
                'album_type_id'             => 2,
                'language_id'           => 3,
                'description'             => 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem.',
                'artist_id'             => 1,
            ],
```

**here track_id is array i am run PHP artisan migrate --seed  show error array to string conversion**

Comment: which type is "track_id" column in the database?

Comment: Of course you can't store an array as a string. You must choose only 1 value from the array. I personally would do this with choosing random key from the array with `array_rand()`.

Comment: track_id is json

Comment: If the field type in the database is `json`, you need to supply it with `json` and not an `array` as you've done in your seeder. Have a look at the [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code :

```
 [
            'id'             => 1,
            'album_title'           => '2022',
            'featured_image'             => 'index_1656159760.jpg',
            'featured_image_url'             => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/artists/albums/featured_image/index_1656159760.jpg',
            'genre_id'           => 4,
            'track_id'             => json_encode(["1","2"]),
            'album_type_id'             => 2,
            'language_id'           => 3,
            'description'             => 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem.',
            'artist_id'             => 1,
        ],
```